# Почему при переходе от сцены menu к 1 lvl все работает корректно, а при переходе обратно сцена menu полностью замораживается и все кнопки не активны

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

В общем я создаю 2д платформер в Unity 2d v2021, есть (пока что, собираюсь расширять к-во сцен(уровней)) 2 сцены, а именно menu и 1 lvl для перехода со сцены menu к сцене 1 lvl написал код для кнопки "старт", точнее для кнопок "выход" и "старт"

```
public void PlayGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);

    }
    public void ExitGame()
    {
        print("game is already closed");
        Application.Quit();
    }
```

а также в сцене "1 lvl" создал "стоп меню", где есть 3 кнопки: продолжить игру, в главное меню, и выйти из игры. Проблема заключается в том что при нажатии на кнопку "главное меню" все хоть и отображается корректно(переход на саму сцену "меню") но все кнопки не работают сцена фактически заморожена, код для игрового меню из сцены "1 lvl":

```
public class Pause_menu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool GameIsPaused = false;
    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;

    public void Resume()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        GameIsPaused = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (GameIsPaused)
            {
                Resume();
            }
            else
            {
                Pause();
            }
        }

    }
    
    void Pause()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameIsPaused = true;
    }
    public void LoadMenu()
    {
       
        SceneManager.LoadScene("menu");
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
    }
    public void QuitGame()
    {
        Debug.Log("Quit ");
        Application.Quit();
    }
```

так как я ещё новичек в этом ремесле я подумал что строка `Time.timeScale = 1f;` должна исправить положение но все усилия оказались тщетны, поэтому как панацею я выбрал обратится к вам.
Помогите пожалуйста. И да было бы неплохо разжевать информацию т.к. я еще не опытный новичок, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй поставить `Time.timeScale = 1` перед загрузкой сцены меню, может поможет